# ODBC for Oracle Connect login window won't go away if user tries to cancel (Access 2013)

Tags: oracle, ms-access, popup, odbc, ms-access-2013

I am managing a split Access database which has the front-end running locally on each user's computer (very small scale -- less than 5 users), and the back-end running on a shared network drive.  However, there are a number of tables stored in an institution-wide Oracle database that we must also reference, so I have linked to them using the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver (they are linked on each front-end, not the back-end).  This works well... for the most part.

If a user does not provide login credentials in the ODBC for Oracle Connect login window and instead hits "Cancel," the window closes (as expected)... but then it reopens.  Repeat ad infinitum.  This prevents the user from doing anything else!

How can I make it so that when a user hits "Cancel" it simply closes the window and does not link to the Oracle tables at all for this session?  The Oracle tables are helpful but not essential for our workflow, so it's important that we still be able to access forms & queries even without the Oracle connection.

Unfortunately, I don't even know where to begin with this... if it is any help, I linked to the Oracle tables by going to the External Data tab, ODBC Database, Machine Data Source, then creating a new Data Source using the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver, which thankfully we all have on our individual machines.  Any guidance is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Can you re-link the tables with the password saved? After you enter your Oracle Password and the box comes up displaying the tables, check the save password box then link the tables.

Comment: I had considered that, but for purposes of accountability each user must log in individually; there are no shared or generic accounts. This also wouldn't help if the user's password changes or they get locked out, which is how this bug was discovered (a user was locked out of Oracle and did not yet have a new password, but needed to use the Access database and could not).

Comment: How are the Oracle tables linked then? You linked them to the front-end individually by each users account?

Comment: @random_answer_guy That's right.  Sorry I wasn't clearer on that -- the Oracle tables are linked on the _front-end_, not the back-end.  That way, each user is able to use their own credentials to access the required tables.  Each time they open the front-end and try to access one of those tables for the first time, it prompts them for their Oracle login, as I mentioned.  Would it make a difference if the tables were linked on the back-end?  My concern is then that every user would be accessing the Oracle tables through my credentials (or whoever last logged in), rather than their own.

Comment: That essentially defeats the purpose of the split database concept. They should be linked to the backend database. Then if your use case requires accountability, you could add some type of logging into the front-end, that captures the user / task they performed.

Comment: @random_answer_guy: IMHO the split database concept only applies to Access tables - they are stored in the backend. Other (ODBC) data sources must be linked in the frontend, if individual logins are required. (If there is no Access backend, because all tables are ODBC, the tables are linked in the frontend too).

Comment: Is there currently any code involved when the Login window is triggered? Or does that happen automatically, when the user first accesses a form/query/table that uses ODBC data?

Comment: @Andre Yes I agree, was just trying to think of a solution where individual logins could be by-passed and still maintain some accountability beyond digging through the log file while still allowing the program to work.

Comment: @Violet: This should be of interest (don't mind that it's for SQL Server): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093266/save-password-for-odbc-connection-to-ms-sql-server-from-ms-access-2007

Comment: @Andre, I have not written any VBA code for the login window; it is automatically triggered as you described.  I checked out the question you linked, and I'm afraid it's a bit beyond me... my coding knowledge is extremely limited.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't seem to sound like it would work for our needs -- I want to ensure that a) a user must _always_ log in to access the Oracle data (at least at session start) and b) if the user cannot log in for some reason, all other forms/data/etc. still function normally, with just "#Error" or similar appearing in the Oracle fields.

Comment: Just want to mention that this is still occurring.  Unfortunately, I have not had much of a chance to toy with it, as it is low priority, but if anyone has any suggestions it is of course greatly appreciated.