# Odd behavior with ODBC driver and Access Azure Login

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I am using Access 365 with ODBC 17 Driver to connect to Azure SQL server.

When the Access is opened for the first time, it connects to Azure and the user gets the MS login form. after entering the password everything works as expected.

However, if the login form is closed and then opened again, the user does not need to enter the password and is sort-of logged in automatically, presumably some Windows cached credentials.

If this is the case I Wonder if there is a way to bypass the login form completely? Belo is a code snippet that sits in the onLoad event of one of the forms that is launched at startup:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim db As DAO.Database

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_AzureLogin

DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.Minimize

Me.img_Disconnected.Visible = False

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Call getUserEmailAddress

conn.Open sConnString <- Debug error here if the login form is closed by a user

If conn.State = 1 Then

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Step1"

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Azure_Login"

Else

    Me.img_Disconnected.Visible = True
    Me.img_Disconnected.ControlTipText = "Unable to connect to Azure."

    Me.lbl_Status.Caption = "Login Failed"

    gUpdateCheck = False
    gTablesRefreshed = False

    Me.TimerInterval = 0

End If
```

I should add I use Active Directory Integrated so only only use the corporate email address as the UID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save password for ODBC connection to MS SQL server from MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093266/save-password-for-odbc-connection-to-ms-sql-server-from-ms-access-2007)

Comment: I have checked it and it doesn't unfortunately. I still get the behaviour described above. Thanks for the suggestion though