# Is there a way for Access pass through queries to be a part of the initial login to the SQL server?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I'm in a situation where I need to use a SQL server as a back end to Access 2010 database.  The problem is that the server is only accessible with a SQL login.  This isn't a big problem for the table part of the database - one login to the server connects all of the tables.  The problem is with stored procedures that must be called.  Since these are not under the ODBC umbrella, each query requires a login.  I can't seem to find a way around that.  Currently, I'm trying setting up pass through queries in Access, but once again - each query has to be logged in to individually.  Is there a way to set up something (query setting, ODBC setting, VB structure or anything!) that will get around this problem of having to log in every time an SP is called?

I'm trying to avoid writing a whole big wrapper that handles the login and holds the password for later connections...

Comment: If the complete ODBC connect string, including password, is stored in the pass-through query, then no separate login is needed - no matter what the PT query runs.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093266/save-password-for-odbc-connection-to-ms-sql-server-from-ms-access-2007

Comment: hmmm... what I get is the user has to log in to connect to tables, but then when the user hits an SP call, he has to log in again.  the question you pointed to is interesting, but the documents that question points to gives me a couple of approaches that may do the job.  I'll get back to you on that.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Andre - your reference to another question was kind of a help, but an article referenced in one of those answers - on the persistance of ODBC connections in Access and how to use them was spot on.  So, you get the win.  I see all the code in here and other sites referencing adding the UID/pwd to the connection string and that's absolutely not necessary.  Once a connection is open, any procedure can reference it.
Here is the link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/
Thanks for your help
Alan